# Bluetooth share: File Unknown file not sent

Tags: android-contentprovider, file-transfer, android-bluetooth

I created a system application to transfer the file from one device to another device over Bluetooth using content Uri of Bluetooth with the help of **BluetoothShare.java** in android 4.2. but it shows the Error message in the toast like **Bluetooth share: File Unknown file not sent**.Please give solution to me ,to transfer the file using Bluetooth as system application.

Thanks in advance.